# jquery click element in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, real-time

I want to click the next button on the slides here - http://engineer.org.in/2011/realtime/ programmatically using JavaScript. The videos is in an iframe.

I tried `$("div.punch-viewer-right").click()` but that didnt work.

Can anybody tell me why this is not working?

Comment: I think you can't because the iframe points to another domain. Your code doesn't work because `$("div.punch-viewer-right").length` is `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) security issues, you can not access the iframe because it is not in the same domain as the website trying to access it.